# From one histogram, create a new histogram from just a mean or median?

Tags: statistics, histogram, data-science

Suppose I have a list of values that I can histogram and calculate descriptive statistics on such as mean, average, max, standard deviation, etc.  Perhaps this histogram is bimodal or right skewed.  Let’s call this group of data “DataSet1”.

Suppose I had just a mean or median of another set of data.  Lets call that DataSet2.  I do not have all the raw data for DataSet2, just the median or mean.  There is a strong belief that DataSet1 and DataSet2 would show the same variability in values.

If I knew just a single value of either mean or median, can I apply the description statistics from DataSet1 to create a new histogram that mirrors the bimodal or right skewed behavior from DataSet1?

Thanks
Dan

Alternative intent:
I have 3 years of historical data, where the data definitely has a "day of week" trend to it. I am using a python api to apply seasonal ARIMA to forecast the next 7 days from the 3 years of historical data. The predicted value is great, but it is only 1 value. I would like to use that predicted value as the "mean" and create a histogram from the variability of values shown to exists historically by day of week.

so, today is thursday. Lets say i predict tomorrow to have a value of 78.6.
I want to sample potential values of tomorrow based upon a mean of 78.6 but with variability similar to that showed to exist on all historical fridays
If i look at historical fridays, perhaps it shows a skewed to the left behavior
so when i sample with a mean of 78.6, if i sampled 100 times, the values sampled, if plotted in a histogram, would also skew to the left

Hope that helps..

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Interesting question, but questions like this which need discussion and analysis are more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This should have been migrated rather than reposted.